# VSCode Pytest Discovers but won't run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

In VScode, pytests are discovered. Using a conda env and it is the selected Python:Interpreter.

However, when I try to run one or all the tests, it just says "Finished running tests!". Can't get into debug. Doesn't give green checkmark or red x's.

If I run `pytest` in the terminal, it works just fine.

I have reinstalled everything and started from scratch. I have no idea what is going on.

Please help! :)

Added Python Test Log. This is the output when I discover and then try to run a test.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Python Test Log]

Comment: Open the Output panel in VS Code (View > Output), and select "Python Test Log" from the dropdown. This might show error messages that can help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the Python Test Log. This is what is output during discovery, and doesn't update when I "run" a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having the following in my .vscode/setting.json fixed the problem:

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "--rootdir=${workspaceFolder}"
          ],
}
```

Comment: Hi lr100, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered.